# Add keyvaluepair from file to Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, addition

I am trying to import values from a .txt file into my `dictionary`.  The .txt file is formatted like this:

Donald Duck, 2010-04-03

And so on... there is 1 entry like that on each line.  My problem comes when I try to add the split strings into the `dictionary`.

I am trying it like this:  `scoreList.Add(values[0], values[1]);`  But it says that names doesn't exist in the context.  I hope someone can point me in the correct direction about this...

Thank you!

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Dictionary<string, DateTime> scoreList = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
          string path = @"list.txt";
          var query = (from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
                       let values = line.Split(',')
                       select new { Key = values[0], Value = values[1] });

          foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DateTime> pair in scoreList)
          {
              scoreList.Add(values[0], values[1]);
          }
          textBox1.Text = scoreList.Keys.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `values` variable are only in scope within the LINQ query. You need to enumerate the query result, and add the values to the dictionary:

```
foreach (var pair in query)
{
    scoreList.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

That being said, LINQ features a `ToDictionary` extension method that can help you here. You could replace your loop with:

```
scoreList = query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Finally, for the types to be correct, you need to convert the Value to `DateTime`using, for instance, `DateTime.Parse`.

Comment: I have problem to display the values in the textBox1  now. 

Im using:

var lines = scoreList.Select(kv => kv.Key + ", " + kv.Value.ToString());
            textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);

but it only gives empty  result,  Do you have any clue to why ?

Comment: Sorry !  I managed to get it working now.  The problem was it gave error message,  when I had entries Key entries in the  .txt  file  with the same names,  System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.   What do I have to look into to take care of that ,  as I have many Keys with the same names then,  maybe a dictionary isnt suitable for that then ?

Answer (score 2):

First you are doing it wrong, you should add item from list not values[0] and values[1] used in LINQ..

```
Dictionary<string, DateTime> scoreList = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

    string path = @"list.txt";

    var query = (from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
                 let values = line.Split(',')
                 select new { Key = values[0], Value = values[1] });

    foreach (var item in query) /*changed thing*/
    {

        scoreList.Add(item.Key, DateTime.Parse(item.Value)); /*changed thing*/
    }

    textBox1.Text = scoreList.Keys.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The *immediate* problem with the code is that `values` only exists in the query expression... your sequence has an element type which is an anonymous type with `Key` and `Value` properties.

The next problem is that you're then iterating over `scoreList`, which will be empty to start with... and there's also no indication of where you plan to convert from `string` to `DateTime`. Oh, and I'm not sure whether `Dictionary<,>.Keys.ToString()` will give you anything useful.

You can build the dictionary simply enough though:

```
var scoreList = File.ReadLines(path)
                    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                    .ToDictionary(bits => bits[0], // name
                                  bits => DateTime.ParseExact(bits[1], // date
                                              "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Note the use of [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) instead of just `DateTime.Parse` - if you know the format of the data, you should use that information.